# Some of my Users can not download the zip?

Tags: java, download, zip

hello so I have been writing an updater for my game.

1) It checks a .version file on drop box and compares it to the local .version file.

2) If there is any link missing from the local version of the file, it downloads the required link one by one.

The issue I am having is  some of the users can download the zips and some cannot.

One of my users who was having the issue was using windows xp. So some of them have old computers.

I was wondering if anyone could help me to get an idea on what could be causing this.

This is the main method that is ran

```
    public void UpdateStart() {
    System.out.println("Starting Updater..");

    if(new File(cache_dir).exists() == false) {
        System.out.print("Creating cache dir.. ");
        while(new File(cache_dir).mkdir() == false);
        System.out.println("Done");
    }


    try {
        version_live = new Version(new URL(version_file_live));
    } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    version_local = new Version(new File(version_file_local));

    Version updates = version_live.differences(version_local);

    System.out.println("Updated");

    int i = 1;
    try {
        byte[] b = null, data = null;
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;


        for(String s : updates.files) {
            if(s.equals(""))
                continue;

            System.out.println("Reading file "+s);
            text = "Downloading file "+ i + " of "+updates.files.size();
            b = readFile(new URL(s));

            progress_a = 0;
            progress_b = b.length;

            text = "Unzipping file "+ i++ +" of "+updates.files.size();

            ZipInputStream zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b));
            File f = null, parent = null;
            ZipEntry entry = null;
            int read = 0, entry_read = 0;
            long entry_size = 0;
            progress_b = 0;

            while((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null)
                progress_b += entry.getSize();

            zipStream = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(b));

            while((entry = zipStream.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                f = new File(cache_dir+entry.getName());
                if(entry.isDirectory())
                    continue;

                System.out.println("Making file "+f.toString());

                parent = f.getParentFile();
                if(parent != null && !parent.exists()) {
                    System.out.println("Trying to create directory "+parent.getAbsolutePath());
                    while(parent.mkdirs() == false);
                }

                entry_read = 0;
                entry_size = entry.getSize();
                data = new byte[1024];
                fos = new FileOutputStream(f);

                while(entry_read < entry_size) {
                    read = zipStream.read(data, 0, (int)Math.min(1024, entry_size-entry_read));
                    entry_read += read;
                    progress_a += read;
                    fos.write(data, 0, read);
                }
                fos.close();
            }

            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(version_file_local), true));
            bw.write(s);
            bw.newLine();
            bw.close();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        this.e = e;
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println(version_live);
    System.out.println(version_local);
    System.out.println(updates);
     try {

     } catch (Exception er) {
         er.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

I have been trying to fix this for the last two days and I am just so stumped at this point

All the best,
Christian

Comment: do you have any exception log. If not I suggest you add one along with your program. Understand one thing you cannot always run your application in debug mode to identify the issue. Logs help in that case. SYSOUT if not captured are of no use

Comment: Nothing shows it runs like everything should it just does not download the files

Comment: I have fixed this my self after hours of looking And you close this please